# symfony 1.4: creating "Copy" action

Tags: php, symfony1, copy, action, models

I need to create "Copy" action for model listing. It should take all values from some model, fill those to forms, you could edit just few fields and after pressing "save" it would create NEW model. At the moment i thought about merging Edit and New actions as so:

```
public function executeListCopy(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
  # EDIT
  # $this->offer = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
  # $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm($this->offer);

  # NEW
  # $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm();
  # $this->offer = $this->form->getObject();

  # COPY
  <..>
   }
```

EDIT section shows what commands symphony runs when i use edit button.
NEW same as edit just creates new model.

i commed up with this:

```
$this->form = $this->configuration->getForm($this->getRoute()->getObject());
$this->job_offer = $this->form->getObject();
```

And i failed. This gives model ID to the form and since id is predefined - it edits, not creates model.

How should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
//routing
job:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model: Job
    module: job
    object_actions: {copy: get, updatecopy: post}
```

Create 2 actions (based on edit and update)

```
class jobActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeCopy(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new JobCopyForm($this->getRoute()->getObject());

    $this->setTemplate('copy');
  }
  public function executeUpdatecopy(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new JobCopyForm($this->getRoute()->getObject());

    $this->processForm($request, $this->form);

    $this->setTemplate('copy');
  }
}
```

copySuccess template is the same as editSuccess, exept that you need to tell the form where to send data:

```
<form action='<?php echo url_for('job_updatecopy', $form->getObject()) ?>' method='post'>
```

Create and configure form, override doSave

```
class JobCopyForm extends BaseJobForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
  }

  public function doSave($conn = null)
  {
    //update object values from form values
    $this->updateObject();
    //clone object
    $job = $this->getObject()->copy();
    //save a clone
    $job->save();

  }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Last two steps gets a little out of directions. All i can find in success template is imports with settings and where exactly models overwrite forms? is it lib/form/addon? If yes under what name? I can't find this part anywhere in Docs.

Comment: editSuccess just includes a form partial. For the sake of simplicity, I just copied the contents of form partial into copySuccess. Alternatively, you can create a form_copy partial, for instance, and include it in copySuccess.