# Copy action in symfony 1.4

Tags: copy, action, symfony-1.4

I also need to create a copy action in symfony. I already looked at these question and answer: [symfony 1.4: creating "Copy" action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581968/symfony-1-4-creating-copy-action). It seems to work fine, but when I try to save a get these error message: "csrf token: CSRF attack detected". I reckon it's because I don't know where to change the form attribute action.

Any help much appreciated!

Here is my code:

actions.class.php:

```
class eventActions extends autoEventActions {

  public function executeCopy(sfWebRequest $request)
  {

    $this->form = new EventCopyForm($this->getRoute()->getObject());
    $this->event = $this->form->getObject();
    $this->setTemplate('copy');
  }

  public function executeUpdatecopy(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new EventCopyForm($this->getRoute()->getObject());
    $this->processForm($request, $this->form);
    $this->setTemplate('copy');
  }
}
```

EvenCopyForm.class.php:

```
class EventCopyForm extends EventForm {

  public function doSave($conn = null)
  {
    $this->updateObject();
    $event = $this->getObject()->copy();
    $event->save();
  }  
}
```

copySuccess.php:

```
<?php use_helper('I18N', 'Date') ?>
<?php include_partial('event/assets') ?>

<div id="sf_admin_container">
  <h1><?php echo __('Copy Event', array(), 'messages') ?></h1>

  <?php include_partial('event/flashes') ?>

  <div id="sf_admin_header">
    <?php include_partial('event/form_header', array('event' => $event, 'form' => $form, 'configuration' => $configuration)) ?>
  </div>
  <div id="sf_admin_content">
    <?php include_partial('event/form', array('event' => $event, 'form' => $form, 'configuration' => $configuration, 'helper' => $helper)) ?>
  </div>
  <div id="sf_admin_footer">
    <?php include_partial('event/form_footer', array('event' => $event, 'form' => $form, 'configuration' => $configuration)) ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it now in a different way: 
+ I get the object as an array:

```
$original->toArray(false);
```

- then unset the id:

  unset($originalValues['id']);
- make a copy object which I save:

  $copy = new Event(); 
  $copy->fromArray($originalValues); 
  $copy->save();

That works fine for me.